# Having trouble compiling with ghc (installed packages aren't found in path) with ghcup and cabal on Mac

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm having trouble compiling my Hakyll site (I know it compiles; the issues is ghc can't find modules that I've installed via cabal (and both of these cleanly installed recently via ghcup). I'm on a new M1 MacBook Pro which I'm guessing is contributing to this problem.

The error upon `ghc --make site.hs`: `Could not find module ‘Hakyll’` and the same for Pandoc and other modules.

#### More info:

I've installed ghc and cabal via ghcup, which are found at `/Users/isaac/.ghcup/bin/ghc` and `/Users/isaac/.ghcup/bin/cabal`. The Pandoc and Hakyll modules are found in `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org`.

`ghc -v` gives me the following:

````sh
isaac@machine notes % ghc -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.10.7, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.10.3
*** initializing package database:
Using binary package database: /Users/isaac/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d/package.cache
package flags []
loading package database /Users/isaac/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.6.1
wired-in package integer-wired-in mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.3.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.14.3.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.16.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.10.7
!!! initializing package database: finished in 9.01 milliseconds, allocated 8.229 megabytes
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.```
````

Comment: Are you trying to use package installed via `cabal install` via bare invocations to `ghc`? By design, `cabal` does not allow that. (See many, many versions of this question here.) Either compile your file through Cabal (i.e. write a package description including that file, presumably as the source of an executable, then build that package) or use `cabal install --package-env <some-dir> <required-packages>` and then run `ghc` from within `<some-dir>` (if you've already run `cabal install <required-packages>` this should not rebuild anything).

Comment: @HTNW that was helpful, I was trying to do that (and believe I was able to do that years ago when I last tried to compile this). I spent quite a while searching for an answer to this without much luck, so thank you!